# Meteor RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded inside future.js

Tags: meteor

I have a little card game where I have a Dealer distributing Cards to Players. This piece of code inside my `game.js` makes Meteor crash with a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

```
Dealer = {
    deal: function(players, deck) {

        for(var j=0; j < players.length; j++) {
            var p = players[j];

            for(var i=0; i < 3; i++) {

                //assign card to player
                var card = deck.shift();
                card.owner = p;
                p.cards.push(card);

            }
        }
    }
};
```

In `/server/main.js` I have a bit of code to setup a new game

```
var table = new Table();

var deck = new Deck();
deck.deck = deck.shuffle();

var trump = deck.deck[_.random(0, 39)];
trump.is_trump = true;

var human = new Player('Human', false);
var computer = new Player('Computer', true);
var players = [human, computer];

console.log('Players: ', players);

//this last line is the one that calls the Dealer above
Dealer.deal(players, deck.deck);
```

How should I go about debugging this error? The exception is thrown around line 245 of future.js by the `card.owner = p` line

Should I be thinking of writing this code in a different way?

Comment: It's probably to little code to tell. Can you provide more context here?